# Is the following sequence increasing or decreasing $ \sqrt{4 n + 1} - n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Well, I can see it is obviously decreasing just by looking at it, but how would I go about proving it?

$$ a_n = \sqrt{4 n + 1} - n $$
$$ n = 1,2,3.. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
a_{n+1}-a_n
&=(\sqrt{4 (n+1) + 1} - (n+1))-(\sqrt{4 n + 1} - n)\\
&=(\sqrt{4 (n+1) + 1}-\sqrt{4 n + 1}) - 1\\
&=(\sqrt{4 (n+1) + 1}-\sqrt{4 n + 1})\dfrac{\sqrt{4 (n+1) + 1}+\sqrt{4 n + 1}}{\sqrt{4 (n+1) + 1}+\sqrt{4 n + 1}} - 1\\
&=\dfrac{(4 (n+1) + 1)-(4 n + 1)}{\sqrt{4 (n+1) + 1}+\sqrt{4 n + 1}} - 1\\
&=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{4 (n+1) + 1}+\sqrt{4 n + 1}} - 1\\
&<\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{4n}+\sqrt{4 n}} - 1\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - 1\\
&\le 0
\qquad\text{for }n \ge 1\\
\text{and}\\
&\le -\dfrac12
\qquad\text{for }n \ge 4\\
\end{array}
$

So, decreasing.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the function $f$ defined for $x\geq 1$ by $f(x) = \sqrt{4x+1} - x$. It is differentiable, and you can easily compute the derivative and see it is negative.

*In short: when you have to prove something over the natural numbers, sometimes proving it over the reals is easier.*

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt{4(n+1)+1}-(n+1)\le\sqrt{4n+1}-n\iff\sqrt{4n+5}-n-1\le\sqrt{4n+1}-n\iff$$

$$\sqrt{4n+5}-1\le\sqrt{4n+1}\stackrel{(**)}\iff4n+6-2\sqrt{4n+5}\le4n+1\iff$$

$$5\le2\sqrt{4n+5}\stackrel{(**)}\iff25\le16n+20\iff16n\ge6$$

and we're done: the sequence is descending.

The two steps marked with (**) follow from the fact that both sides in the inequality are positive for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing because the positive
square root term
is overwhelmed by the
-n term.

Answer (score 0):

Putting $x = \sqrt{4n + 1}$, we have:
$$
a_n = x - \frac{x^2 - 1}{4} = \frac{1 + 4x - x^2}{4} = \frac{5 - (x - 2)^2}{4},
$$
and this decreases with $x$, because $x > 2$ for all $n \geqslant 1$.

Therefore $a_n$ decreases with $n$, because $x$ increases with $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n\ge1$, then, by AGM (${a+b\over2}\ge\sqrt{ab}$), we have

$${\sqrt{4n+5}+\sqrt{4n+1}\over2}\ge\sqrt[4]{(4n+5)(4n+1)}\gt\sqrt[4]{16n^2}\ge\sqrt[4]{16}=2$$

so that

$$1\gt{4\over\sqrt{4n+5}+\sqrt{4n+1}}=\sqrt{4n+5}-\sqrt{4n+1}$$

and thus

$$a_n=\sqrt{4n+1}-n\gt\sqrt{4n+5}-(n+1)=a_{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{4x+1}-x$. Note that 
$$
f'(x)=\frac{4}{2\sqrt{4x+1}}-1=\frac{2-\sqrt{4x+1}}{\sqrt{4x+1}}
$$
Since $2=\sqrt{4}<\sqrt{4x+1}$ for $1\leq x$, if follows that $f'(x)<0$ for $1\leq x$, so $f(x)$ is decreasing for $1\leq x$. Therefore, $f(n)=\sqrt{4n+1}-n$ for every natural number $n$.

Comment: thank @Barry Cupra, I edit the answer again